# clang produces symbolized stack trace with offsets

Tags: c++, clang

I use clang in order to find UndefinedBehavior errors. I use the following options for debuger and linker:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x -fsanitize=undefined -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fsanitize=undefined
```

Also I have defined path to the llvm-symbolizer and run my program with `UBSAN_OPTIONS=print_stacktrace=1` parameter:

```
export UBSAN_OPTIONS=print_stacktrace=1
./vapp # run my application.
```

I see that I have runtime error and see corresponding call stack:

```
runtime error: ^[[1m^[[0m^[[1mload of misaligned address 0x7faf2411b514 for type 'PlayableItem *const', which requires 8 byte alignment.

   #4 0x59abba  (/home/rkazmin/repo_dev/repobuild_debug/vapp+0x59abba)^M
    #5 0x17eb820  (/home/rkazmin/repo_dev/repobuild_debug/vapp+0x17eb820)^M
    #6 0x17f495b  (/home/rkazmin/repo_dev/repobuild_debug/vapp+0x17f495b)^M
```

I have expected that call stack will show me code lines where error is happened - instead of I see offsets vapp+0x59abba and etc... 
How can I match these offsets and source code in my vapp?